# Flutter: Multiple Tap Gestures for Text

Tags: flutter, text, hyperlink, gesture-recognition

I'm looking for a way to add multiple tap gestures to a block of text.

The block of text may consist of a hyperlink. The goal is that if a user taps on the link, navigate to that web page. If they tap anywhere else on the block of text, navigate to a detail view.

I am using Linkable to detect the links. That portion works as expected, but the other tap does not.

Here is what I have tried:

```
return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
        AutoRouter.of(context).push(
          // Detailed Page
        );
      }
    },
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Linkable(
        text: myText,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        linkColor: Colors.blue,
     ),
   ),
);
```

Comment: Did you give GestureDetector a try?

Comment: Yes, GestureDetector & InkWell. Both do not work in the way I need them to.

Comment: The problem I found with both GestureDetector and Inkwell is that the onTap gets called generally around the text and not over the text item itself. Not sure if the Linkable package is preventing additional gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget to break your texts into TextSpans. Add the following code to the TextSpan you want to make clickable.

```
 TextSpan(
   text: "Clickable text.",
   style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.blue,
   ),
   recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
    ..onTap = () {
      doStuff();
    },
 ),
```

Comment: hmm... possibly but this could become rather complex as I'd need to search through the text to find the URLs, etc. that will link to other sources.